# How to send ether from eoa to contract

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I need to send ether from externally owned account to contract. 
All code I found so far looks like this

```
contract Contract {
   mapping (address => uint) balances;

   event Transfer(address indexed _from, uint256 _value);

   function deposit() public returns (uint) {
      balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
      Transfer(msg.sender, msg.value);
      return balances[msg.sender];
   }
}
```

But I can not understand how does it work. I thought it should look like this: we should run some send function which will take current contract address, sender address and amount.

Can someone explain me the logic behind it?

I also found the solution which correspond to this logic

```
contract Contract {
   function pay() payable {}
}
```

and than call it from console like that

```
var contract
Contract.deployed().then(function(instance) { contract = instance; })
contract.pay.sendTransaction({from: eoa_address,to: contract_address,value: web3.toWei(amount,"ether"), gas:1000000})
```

But in this case `sendTransaction` function called outside of contact.
Is there any way of calling it like from `this` perspective inside contract?

Answer (score 2):

to send Ether to a contract :

we could create a payable function if we need to pay to execute this function

```
contract Contract {
   function do_somthing() payable {
action1
action2 
...
}
}
```

if we want to just send ethers to the contract without executing any function we define the fallback function as you presented in your question :

```
contract Contract {
   function pay() payable {}
}
```

the example you have provided before :
contract Contract {

```
   mapping (address => uint) balances;

   event Transfer(address indexed _from, uint256 _value);

   function deposit() public returns (uint) {
      balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
      emit Transfer(msg.sender, msg.value);
      return balances[msg.sender];
   }
}
```

is recording the balances sent by the users to the contract (this function needs to be declared as payable for the recent compiler : `function deposit() public payable  returns`)

```
function deposit() public payable returns (uint) {
      balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
      emit Transfer(msg.sender, msg.value); 
      return balances[msg.sender];
   }
```

Comment: To clarify a bit things like msg.value and msg.sender are so called automatic or global variables. So you don't need to pass these as arguments see http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html

Comment: what do you clarify by that?

Comment: I thought that Maria did not understand why things like msg.value and msg.sender where not passed as function arguments. Maybe my wording was in correct and should have been 'To add on that'. Because I missed that part in your answer.

Comment: @Badr Bellaj   Can you say how deposit function should be called from let's say testrpc console? So that value amount of ethers will be transferred from eoa to contract account.